# Newly opened Excel not counted on Workbooks.Count

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that waits for another application to generate a new Workbook, however, as I run Workbooks.Count it doesn't count the newly generated file.

It seems that the new Workbook opens on a different instance of Excel, with its own VBA Project Window.

Additionally, if I try to open a new Workbook manually, same thing happens. Problem is solved by saving the Workbook and opening it again. Is there a workaround where I don't need to save and re-open the workbook?

Comment: Without providing the code you're using, how could we troubleshoot?